# Not able to post data using $resource

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm not able to figure out how to use $resource to POST data to create a new user. GET and DELETE are working fine though. I've spent a long time trying different ways given on the net, but still not able to implement them. Can anyone please suggest a way out?

Here's my HTML form

```
<input type="text" ng-model="customer.first_name" placeholder="Name">
<input type="text" ng-model="customer.gender" placeholder="Gender">
<input type="number" ng-model="customer.phone_primary" placeholder="Phone Number">

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="createCustomer()"> Submit</button>
```

Here's the service.js code

```
.factory('CustomersFactory', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8000/pos/customers/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
        update: {method: 'POST'}
    });
})];
```

And finally here's the controller.js

```
.controller('CustomerCtrl', ['$scope','$http', '$location','$resource','CustomersFactory',
    function($scope, $http, $location, $resource, CustomersFactory) {

//Get the list of all customers - working fine

$scope.customerList = CustomersFactory.query();

//Delete a user with given customerId - working fine
$scope.deleteCustomer = function (customerId) {
    CustomersFactory.delete({ id: customerId });
    $scope.customerList = CustomersFactory.query();
};

//And here's the one for posting data which is not working

$scope.createCustomer = function() {
    CustomersFactory.update($scope.customer,function(data) {
        $scope.customerList.push(data);
    });
```

Here's the response I'm getting on console -

> 'POST localhost:8000/pos/customers 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)'

The code runs fine when I use the $http createCustomer method instead of $resource. Here's the code

```
$scope.createCustomer = function (customer) {
$http.post('http://localhost:8000/pos/customers/',customer); }
```

Comment: The `POST` request is being fired correctly?

Comment: Its giving me a "500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)"

Comment: Si its server error, not client side. Or validate that you sent proper data

Comment: and its works fine when I use $http. here's the working code - ' $scope.createCustomer = function (customer) {
        $http.post('http://localhost:8000/pos/customers/', customer);}' @Beterraba

Comment: You might need ,params: {id: '@id'} along with method: "POST"

Comment: @Ankit Can you edit your question and include the request, as seen on console?

Comment: Try: a) Make an empty post request. Is there error still "500"? Make sure you are passing all the correct values. Is the error still "500"? Then your server is broken.

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat the code runs fine when I try with $http. So the server seems to be working fine. I think there's some error in the $scope.createCustomer() function.

Answer (score 0):

$resource has method 'save' which saves data via 'POST' http method

```
.factory('CustomersFactory', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8000/pos/customers');
}]);
```

than in your controller

```
.controller('CustomerCtrl', ['$scope','$http', '$location','$resource','CustomersFactory',
    function($scope, $http, $location, $resource, CustomersFactory) {
    CustomersFactory.save({customer: $scope.customer}, function(data) {
        $scope.customerList.push(data);
    })
}
```

your server should deserialize json object in posted field 'customer'